# Linux Distros For The iMac G3?

Tags: mac, debian, distro-recommendation

What Versions Of Ubuntu/Debian or Ubuntu/Debian Based Disros Can Run On A iMac G3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) - AFAIK there's not any version of Ubuntu that supports the Motorola PowerPC G3

Comment: Ubuntu now only supports *ppc64el*, the last to support *ppc* was 14.04 for main Ubuntu (now EOL with no ESM available), or 16.04 via *flavors*. No mac ppc can run *ppc64el* or the 64-bit modern ppc (power pc)